# Eclipse Luna: Indentation size for xml is not editable

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

[image]

I am trying to edit the indentation size for xml in Eclipse Luna on Ubuntu 12.04
I am not able to edit it. 
I remember being able to edit it on a different version of Linux/Ubuntu.

Is there a reason why this is not editable?

Please let me know if posting any other information would be helpful to troubleshoot this.

Thanks Awesome people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in Eclipse WST. It has been reported as bug [428246](http://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=428246). There is no workaround listed.